# All the functions that satisfy an integral condition

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I need to find a caractherize the function $A(a, b)$ such that
\begin{align}
\int_0^xA(x+y, z-\frac{x+y}{2})z dz+\int_0^yA(x+y, z-\frac{x+y}{2})z dz=\alpha x^2+\alpha y^2+\beta xy,
\end{align}
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two constants.

It is a problem that comes from a physical problem and I tried to derive both sides respect to $x$ and $y$ but I didn't succed in characterizing all the functions $A$ that satisfy that condition.

Has someone an idea?

Thank you

Comment: Two ideas:
1) You can always try a power series ansatz for $A(a,b)$ for these kinds of problems. It can get very messy here though, since there are several variables.
2) You can try solving this for some special cases first (like $x=y$) and maybe you can see some pattern from there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't understoood very well the first suggestion but I will try soon with the second one. Thanks again